# How to force Angular not to ecnapsulate nested rules?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have simple requirement to style header section of `mat-tab-group`. Following rule applies more then fine

```
   mat-tab-group.buttons-tab { 
      > .mat-tab-header {
        ... some more rules 
      }
  }
```

However, this must be done global CSS while I would like to encapsulate it in used component (as this is the only place this custom style will be used).
Angular is encapsulating `buttons-tab`class , but it is encapsulating `.mat-tab-header` as well. This encapsulation prevents rule from applience since internal `mat-tab-headers` are not ecapsulated. **Turning off encapsulation for my component is not an option** as it contains more styles that needs encapsulation.

So the questions are

1. Is it possible turn off encapsulation for nested rules?
2. Maybe it is possible to add multiple style files to `@Component` and set encapsulation for every file separately.
3. Is using global styles (or turning off encapsulation) the only working solution?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I don't think the way angular adds the encapsulation selector every nested level makes any sense. It is unnecessary and changes the specificity of rules depending on how you did nesting.

Comment: When I read it now, I think that :ng-deep will do the trick

Answer (score -2):

In the component that you want to prevent view encapsulation you might put the code (Inside @Component block):

```
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Read more about that here:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

Comment: Did you even read my post? I have wrote important statement in **BOLD** for you.

Comment: Sorry. What if you put the part that should not be encapsulated to a small child component?